# Is it possible to have two private registries with different authentication data in .npmrc?

Tags: npm, artifactory

There is an npm package on `artifactory_1` which is private. This means that the `_auth` property in `.npmrc` contains the authentication data for `artifactory_1` in base64 and `always-auth` is set to `true`. This way the `npm install` works, the private package can be downloaded from `artifactory_1` because the authentication data is provided from the `_auth` property.

Now I have an other private package on an other private artifactory (may it be `artifactory_2`). I want to use the private package of `artifactory_2` in the same project, where `artifactory_1` is already configured with its authentication data.
This means, that I should somehow add the new registry and the authentication data of it to the `.npmrc`. It should be possible to use the private package from  `artifactory_1` and the private package from `artifactory_2` at the same time.

[It is documented here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/npm+Registry), how is it possible to handle one private package in a project.
But I do not find any documentation/example for more private packages from different artifactories.

Any idea how should this be done? Is this even possible, what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not make it to use repos from two different artifactories. I migrated the content of the first artifactory into a repo of the second artifactory. After that I was able to create a virtual repository, that showed the content of the two repos as one. This virtual repo is set up in my project as registry and this way I'm able to install the content of the two repos.